# Vuejs how to change element content using innerHtml

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

Hello there I would like to know how can I change the `<h3 id="score">` `innerHtml` when the button is clicked.

[image]

In Vanilla Javascript I can access the element with:

`const score = document.querySelector('#score');`

and change it by doing this:

`score.innerHtml = "13";`

something like that.

```
<template>
  <div id="scoreboard">
    <h4>{{header_my}}</h4>
    <button v-on:click="changeH3()">Change</button>
    <h3 id="score">0</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "scoreboard",
  data() {
    return {
      header_my: "Hello Wolrd"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeH3() {
      const h3 = document.querySelector("#score");
      h3.innerHtml = "12";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

How can I do this, when `changeH3` is called? The `innerHtml` of `h3` with `id` of `score` must change to `12`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not manipulate DOM directly when using Vue.js. First off define `score` data property. Vue knows when you change `score` and will make DOM manipulations to update the view.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#scoreboard",
  data() {
    return {
      header_my: "Hello Wolrd",
      score: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeScore() {
      this.score = 12;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="scoreboard">
  <button @click="changeScore">Change</button>
  <h3>{{ score }}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: so I can't use innerHtml and appendChild when using vue?

Comment: Of course you can, but you should do it in "Vue" style, using `v-show` or `v-if` on your child, and display the child conditionally.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

And just like this it's done:

```
let html = "<b>some text</b>"  
<div v-html="html" />
```

Comment: Brilliant!  And this shows once more how powerful Vue3 is